# Jquery adding two values together, returning sum of both values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add two values together, and append that value to a div. The value is saying "0" when value1 = 30 and value2 = 3.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {


var value1 = $(".value1").val();
var value2 = $(".value2").val();
var sum = addnumbers(value1,value2);
$(".sum").append(sum);

function addnumbers(value1,value2){
  var sum=Number(value1)+Number(value2);
  return sum;
};

});

</script>
```

Html is pretty evident:

`<div class="value1">30</div>`
`<div class="value2">3</div>`
`<div class="sum"></div>`

Comment: Can you please paste your html here?

Comment: you code works http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8zv8pak1/

Comment: in your code use .text()  instead of .val()

Comment: Please read the documentation about [**`val`**](https://api.jquery.com/val/). How come you used it if you don't know how it works?

Comment: Your code only works if ".value1" and ".value2" are input types. If they are anything else (i.e. `div`) `.text()` should be used over `.val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with divs ***(in your case)*** you need to use `.text()` .. `.val()` with inputs , select

```
var value1 = $(".value1").text();
var value2 = $(".value2").text();
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I need to look at the documentation for val.. I have appended. Thanks ")

Comment: @meeb0  yes you will find it more simple as you think .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
var value1 = $(".value1").text(); // or html (in your html both are same)
var value2 = $(".value2").text();
```

`div` doesn't have `value` attribute.

so either use `.html()` or `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` only works for inputs. For any other HTML element to get the html within you can use `.html()` or `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="value1">30</div> 
<div class="value2">3</div> 
<div class="sum"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sum").append(addnumbers($(".value1").html(),$(".value2").html()));
});

function addnumbers(value1,value2){
  return (Number(value1)+Number(value2));
};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3q4Lgfkz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahtcjj9c/)

Code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var value1 = $(".value1").html();
var value2 = $(".value2").html();

function addnumbers(value1,value2){
  var sum = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
  return sum;
};
    var sum = addnumbers(value1,value2);
    $(".sum").append(sum);
});
```

```html
<div class='value1'>2</div>
<div class='value2'>4</div>
<div class='sum'></div>
```